# JavascriptExecutor works in one way but not in another

Tags: selenium

```
public class A{
     WebDriver    driver;
     JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

     @Test
     js.executeScript("alert('hello world');");
      }
```

doesn't work; whereas

```
 public class A{
    WebDriver    driver;
    @Test
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;    
    js.executeScript("alert('hello world');");
    }
```

works fine.I can't understand why?

Comment: As in the particular value is not assigned to #display SSn. Essentially, I'm testing a textbox on a webpage using selenium web driver which gets the value through a java-script variable. I was trying to assign a integer value to this variable using the above command. And to my surprise, I can't assign a value to #DisplaySsn through the first piece of code whereas the other works, which according to me is same as the first.

Comment: in other words, the javascript in the first block doesn't does what is expected of it, but I'm able to achieve the objective using the one in  the 2nd block. Now that surprises me, as I think that the codes in both the blocks should convey the same meaning anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that is the code you have then the first example wouldn't work because you would be assigning null to the JavascriptExecutor, because you have not instantiated the driver at the point you instantiated the executor.  In the second example I assume you did in some setup method.

This might just be because your code to illustrate your example is wrong though...